# c++: making a shared object from a static library

Tags: c++, fortran, shared-libraries, static-libraries

we are trying to make a c++ shared object library to interface with a static fortran library (compiled with mpif90). There is one fortran wrapper file compiled with gfortran or mpif90 (both fail) and one c++ wrapper file compiled with g++

The compilation command is

```
g++ -std=c++11 -ftemplate-depth-256 -Wno-inline -fPIC -O3 -pthread -fopenmp -v  -I /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/openmpi/include/ -I /opt/local/nextsim/modules/oasis/include -o /opt/local/nextsim/lib/liboasis.so.1.0 /opt/local/nextsim/objs/./oasis_cpp_interface.o /opt/local/nextsim/objs/./oasis_cpp_interface_ftn.o /docker_io/compile_oa3-mct/lib/libpsmile.MPI1.a /docker_io/compile_oa3-mct/lib/libmct.a /docker_io/compile_oa3-mct/lib/libmpeu.a /docker_io/compile_oa3-mct/lib/libscrip.a -fopenmp -Wl,-rpath,/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/openmpi/lib/ -L /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/openmpi/lib/ -lmpi_cxx -lmpi -ldl -lstdc++ -lpthread -L /docker_io/compile_oa3-mct/lib -Wl,-rpath,/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu -L /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu -lnetcdff -shared -Wl,-soname,liboasis.so.1
```

The error it gives is:

```
/usr/bin/x86_64-linux-gnu-ld: /docker_io/compile_oa3-mct/lib/libpsmile.MPI1.a(mod_oasis_auxiliary_routines.o): relocation R_X86_64_PC32 against symbol `__mod_oasis_data_MOD_mpi_comm_local' can not be used when making a shared object; recompile with -fPIC
/usr/bin/x86_64-linux-gnu-ld: final link failed: Bad value
```

As you can see we already compiled with -fPIC (as was the fortran library and the c++ objects). I also tried linking the fortran objects instead of the libraries, but they were also using some other static libraries which gave the same error.

Actually for some reason, our code compiles on one particular server, but not another, and not inside docker (ubuntu) so the problem is a little puzzling.

Comment: You really should compile all other libraries with -fPIC, not just the final one. You cannot take executable code from a compiled static library and just insert it into a final dynamic library.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `-fPIC` option is ineffective in your commandline:

```
g++ -std=c++11 -ftemplate-depth-256 -Wno-inline -fPIC -O3 -pthread -fopenmp -v \
-I /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/openmpi/include/ -I /opt/local/nextsim/modules/oasis/include \
-o /opt/local/nextsim/lib/liboasis.so.1.0 \
/opt/local/nextsim/objs/./oasis_cpp_interface.o \
/opt/local/nextsim/objs/./oasis_cpp_interface_ftn.o \
/docker_io/compile_oa3-mct/lib/libpsmile.MPI1.a \
/docker_io/compile_oa3-mct/lib/libmct.a \
/docker_io/compile_oa3-mct/lib/libmpeu.a \
/docker_io/compile_oa3-mct/lib/libscrip.a \
-fopenmp -Wl,-rpath,/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/openmpi/lib/ \
-L /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/openmpi/lib/ \
-lmpi_cxx -lmpi -ldl -lstdc++ -lpthread -L /docker_io/compile_oa3-mct/lib \
-Wl,-rpath,/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu \
-L /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu -lnetcdff \
-shared -Wl,-soname,liboasis.so.1
```

because `-fPIC` is a *compilation* option and this is a *linkage* command. No source files
are input. Compilation has already been done. The other compilation options in this commandline:

```
std=c++11 -ftemplate-depth-256 -Wno-inline -fopenmp
-I /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/openmpi/include/ -I /opt/local/nextsim/modules/oasis/include \
```

are also redundant.

The linker says that the object file `libpsmile.MPI1.a(mod_oasis_auxiliary_routines.o)`,
i.e. member `mod_oasis_auxiliary_routines.o` of the archive `libpsmile.MPI1.a`, was not
compiled with `-fPIC`. You say that:

> we already compiled with -fPIC (as was the fortran library and the c++ objects).

but it's more likely that `-fPIC` was not used in the compilation of
the object files in `libpsmile.MPI1.a` than that the linker is mistaken.

Recompile all the object files input to the linkage, including those within static libraries, ensuring that `-fPIC` is enabled. *All* object files that are linked into a shared library must be Position-Independent-Code.

Comment: thanks for this explanation. I realised the original libraries were not compiled with -fPIC, and adding this flag got me past the original error. However, now I get a similar error
`/usr/bin/x86_64-linux-gnu-ld: /docker_io/compile_oa3-mct/lib/libpsmile.MPI1.a(GPTLget_memusage.o): relocation R_X86_64_PC32 against symbol ``stderr@@GLIBC_2.2.5' can not be used when making a shared object; recompile with -fPIC
/usr/bin/x86_64-linux-gnu-ld: final link failed: Bad value`
Is this saying the problem is now with one of the system libraries?

Comment: Either you have not recompiled `GPTLget_memusage.o` with `-fPIC`, or you
have not updated the archive member `libpsmile.MPI1.a(GPTLget_memusage.o)` with
the new object file. The information we need but do not have is *exactly how you are building* `libpsmile.MPI1.a`

Comment: The library is a mixture of fortran90 and c files. `GPTLget_memusage.o` came from a c file, so after adding -fPIC to `CCFLAGS` as well as the `F90FLAGS` the shared object compiled. Thanks again

Comment: Glad to hear it :)